# Silverstripe Page Type Missing

Tags: silverstripe

I have recently started a new job and as part of it I have inherited a silverstripe website which I am relatively new to working with. The previous developer they hired to build the site has 19 different page types and I need to edit one of them directly.

I have navigated to `themes/default/templates/layout` and found 15 of the `.ss` templates but the one I need is not there, is there somewhere else in the directory structure you can place `.ss` files in silverstripe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are familiar with PHP, follow the names of the class hierarchy up to Page, as templates are inherited, just as a class inherits properties.

If you're not familiar with PHP (or class based inheritance programming at all), then long story short: It will default to using another template that does exist, probably look at Page.ss

https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/3.3/developer_guides/templates/template_inheritance/

Answer (score 1):

You may find `.ss` template files in a few other places.

**First** (where you have mentioned): `themes/default/templates/layout`

**Second:** `themes/default/templates/`

**Third:** `mysite/code/...` - Sometimes a developer may create a 'templates' folder in here so it would be `mysite/code/templates`

**Fourth:** Could be in a module that you are using...

The other thing you could do is in your code editor/IDE, do a project search for just `.ss` files and that should find the ones that you haven't found yet. Hopefully that helps :)

Answer (score 0):

A quick and dirty solution:

1. What is the *actual* theme being used? (Find out in the CMS' "Settings" area)
2. Armed with this (say it really is "default") then open: `themes/default/templates/Page.ss`
3. At the very top edit it and write: `<h1>$ClassName</h1>`
4. Given that all pagetypes use Page.ss, then it won't matter which URL you go to, at the top will be displayed in <h1> markup, containing the name of the pagetype's class.

From there, as other posters have noted, use your O/S's native "find" or "search" feature (find + grep are your friends on OS X / Unix / Linux) and look for whatever `$ClassName` printed. E.g. if `$ClassName` printed: "HomePage" then you'd search for "HomePage.ss".

As other posters have also noted, if you don't find a matching `.ss` template file, then your mystery pagetype will be using `themes/default/templates/Layout/Page.ss` by default. You can override this my creating a new file named exactly for your mystery class ala: `themes/default/templates/Layout/MyMysteryClass.ss` and voila, you have the ability to completely re-style this pagetype's layout and design should you wish to do so.